# TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object while using split and spell

Tags: python-3.x, string, text

I have selected the string columns from my df.

```
string_dtypes = df.convert_dtypes().select_dtypes("string")
```

Trying to split and correct spellings of words in the text using Speller library.

```
df[string_dtypes.columns] = string_dtypes.apply(lambda x: " ".join([spell(i) for i in x.str.split()]))
```

But I run into the error -

> TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

I tried using the x.split method too, but still, I am facing an error.

How to resolve this?

I don't have any null values and dtypes are string.

Answer (score 0):

Can you also add a `print(type(x))` with your `lambda x` to let you know which type it is encountering.